# How to program a switch to read YouTubePlayerState in Swift?

Tags: swift, youtube, youtube-api, switch-statement

I want my YouTubePlayer State to change a public variable in my view controller.  I'm having trouble with the YTPlayer Delegate function and the switch.  Here is my var...

```
var ytps = String!
```

here is the youtube state function...

```
func playerView(player: YTPlayerView!, didChangeToState state: YTPlayerState)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
        case YTPlayerState.Ended:
            // handle ended state
            print("Ended")

            break;

        case YTPlayerState.Paused:
            // handle paused state
            print("Paused")

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

How can I get the state of either YTPlayerState.Ended or YTPlayerState.Paused to change the value of my empty string to "Ended/Paused"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just replace `print("Paused")` and `print("Ended")` with `ytps = "Paused"` and `ytps = "Ended"`. Full example:

```
var ytps = String()

func playerView(player: YTPlayerView!, didChangeToState state: YTPlayerState) {
    switch state {
        case YTPlayerState.Ended:
            ytps = "Ended"
            break
        case YTPlayerState.Paused:
            ytps = "Paused"
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem may be where I'm reading ytps.  Currently I'm doing this in viewDidLoad.  Where should I view an event change after the view has been loaded?

Comment: You'll need to update the label with the status inside of `didChangeToState`